# Equivalent Definition of a support of a function

Tags: measure-theory

$$Supp(f(x))= \overline{\{x \in \mathbb{R} |f(x) \neq 0\}}$$

**My question:**

How is the support of the function f, equals $ \{f^\mathrm{o}=0\}^c$? where $f^\mathrm{o}$ is the interior of $f$.

**My Approach**

$$Supp(f(x))= \overline{\{x \in \mathbb{R} |f(x) \neq 0\}} = \overline{\{x \in \mathbb{R} |f(x)\gt 0 \text{ or } f(x) \lt 0\}}$$

If we take the compliment we get, $$\overline{\{x \in \mathbb{R} |f(x)\gt 0 \text{ or } f(x) \lt 0\}}^c= \big[\big(\{x \in \mathbb{R} |f(x)\gt 0 \text{ or } f(x) \lt 0\}\big)^c\big]^0$$.

How to proceed from this step to get the final result?

Comment: What do you mean by "the interior of a function"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any topological space we always have $(A^{0})^{c}=\overline {A^{c}}$. Take $A=\{x:f(x)=0\}$.

Comment: Is $\big(\{x:f(x)=0\}\big)^0 =  \big(\{x:f^0(x)=0\}\big)$?. If so, can you please explain me with the help of an example.

Comment: There is no such thing as interior of  a function. You have copied the question wrongly. @AtulAnuragSharma

Comment: Yeah, I also never heard about it. It was taught in the class today, maybe I copied it wrongly. There was a doubt in my mind about it so I posted.